# design library of android sdk 20

Tags: android

I am working on a project which was targeting SDK version 23 but I had to change it to 20 and consequently I have to change `com.android.support:appcompat` and `com.android.support:design`

I set `appcompat` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0` and it works fine, but I can not find not what to change `design` to.

Thank you

Comment: Please explain what you want.

Comment: When I go to design in the layout files, all I get is a grey screen. How do I fix that? I am a noob in android. Sorry for these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [Picking your compileSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, and targetSdkVersion blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd):

> Therefore it is strongly recommended that you **always compile with the latest SDK.** You’ll get all the benefits of new compilation checks on existing code, avoid newly deprecated APIs, and be ready to use new APIs.
>
> Note that if you use the Support Library, compiling with the latest SDK is a *requirement* for using the latest Support Library releases.

There is no Design Library prior to 23.0.0, so you must compile with API 23.

However, the blog also says:

> It should be emphasized that **changing your compileSdkVersion does not change runtime behavior.**

You can target a lower SDK version than you compile with, allowing you to (conditionally) use new APIs and use new versions of the Support Library, while keeping the compatibility modes controlled by targetSdkVersion at a lower SDK.

Comment: But how do I fix the grey screen that I receive in the design tab in the layout files?

Comment: @zeeks - that sounds like a totally different question that should contain your code, version of Android Studio, version of the Design Library, and a picture of what you are seeing. I'd first make sure you are on the latest of all dependencies (and then create a new question for any further issues).